# command/CMD in docker-compose is not equivalent to CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that uses a volume in its entrypoint. for example

```
CMD bash /some/volume/bash_script.sh
```

I moved this to compose but it only works if my compose points to a Dockerfile in the `build` section if I try to write the same line in the `command` section is not acting as I expect and throws file not found error.

I also tried to use `docker-compose run <specific service> bash /some/volume/bash_script.sh` which gave me the same error.

The question is - Why dont I have this volume at the time that the docker-compose 'command' is executed? Is there anyway to make this work/ override the CMD in my dockerfile?

EDIT:
I'll show specifically how I do this in my files:

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  base:
    build: 
      context: ..
      dockerfile: BaseDockerfile
    volumes:
      code:/volumes/code/
  my_service:
    volumes:
      code:/volumes/code/
    container_name: my_service
    image: my_service_image
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    build: 
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

volumes:
  code:

BaseDockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /volumes/code/

COPY code.py code.py
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server \
alien \
unixodbc 

WORKDIR /volumes/code/


CMD python code.py;
```

This works.

But if I try to add to docker-compose.yml this line:

```
command: python code.py
```

Then this file doesnt exist at the command time. I was expecting this to behave the same as the CMD command

Comment: Does the `Dockerfile` also have an `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: No.. it only has CMD

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example?  Those two things should mean the same thing.  (Though the `/some/volume` reference in the Dockerfile seems questionable; what do you do if the volume isn't mounted?)

Comment: See edit. I know its not good practice to put the code in volumes, but we need it and it works fine with the Dockerfile CMD. The question is why is the CMD in the dockerfile is different than command in docker-compose and how can I override it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm, nice point!
`command: python code.py` is not exactly the same as `CMD python code.py;`!
Since the first one is interpreted as a **shell-form** command, where the latter is interpreted as an **exec-form** command.
The problem is about the differences in these two types of *CMD*s. (i.e. `CMD ["something"]` vs `CMD "something"`).
For more info about these two, see [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-63-difference-between-an-array-and-string-based-cmd).

But, you may still be thinking of what's wrong with your example?
In your case, based on the specification of *YAML* format, `python code.py` in the `command: python code.py` will be interpreted as a single string value, not an array!
On the other hand, as you've probably guessed, `python code.py;` in the above-mentioned Dockerfile is interpreted as an array, which provides an **exec-form** command.

Answer (score 2):

The (partial) answer is that the error that was thrown was not at all what the problem was. 
Running the following command: `bash -c 'python code.py'` worked fine. I still cant explain why there was a difference between CMD in Dockerfile and docker-compose "command" oprtion. but this solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I found out this will work:

```
command: python ./code.py
```